# Inserting SVG as string works, but not as element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to store SVG icons as `<symbol>` markup in localStorage and then insert them after `DOMContentLoaded`.

Ideally, I would use `document.createElement('svg')` and insert the element before the first node in `document.body`.

However (at least in Chrome) the icon won't appear unless I set innerHTML of a div to be the string representation of the `<svg>` element *and then* insert the div into the document.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
var sprites = document.getElementById('sprites');

var circles = [
  '<symbol id="circle-yellow"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="yellow" /></symbol>',
  '<symbol id="circle-blue"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="blue" /></symbol>'
];

// Insert the yellow circle symbol by creating an SVG element.
var yellowDiv = document.createElement('div');
var yellow = document.createElement('svg');
yellow.innerHTML = circles[0];
yellowDiv.appendChild(yellow);
sprites.appendChild(yellowDiv);

// Insert the blue circle symbol by inserting the SVG string.
var blueDiv = document.createElement('div');
blueDiv.innerHTML = '<svg>' + circles[1] + '</svg>';
sprites.appendChild(blueDiv);
```

```css
#sprites {
  dispay: none;
}

svg {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<svg height="50" width="50"><use href="#circle-yellow"></use></svg>

<svg height="50" width="50"><use href="#circle-blue"></use></svg>

<!-- Will hold <svg> elements referred to by <use> elements. -->
<div id="sprites"></div>
```

Why does the yellow circle not appear?

I suspect is has something to do with the `<svg>` element for the yellow circle not appearing as a 150x300 box at the bottom of the page (which confuses me, because both `<svg>` elements are children of a div with `display: none`, and neither should be visible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug `document.createElement('svg').constructor`, you'll see that it's actually created as an `HTMLUnknownElement`:

```
> document.createElement('svg').constructor;
< ƒ HTMLUnknownElement() { [native code] }
```

This is because SVG isn't part of HTML; it has to be namespaced to work. Try this:

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
```